# Firefox extension testing and developing - I'm confused

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

when I'm writing extension for Google Chrome, I only create "manifest.json" file and  JS file, which is my script. after installing ,   I can change anything in the code, I only refresh browser and I had changed version of extension.

1) Can I change some code after installing Firefox extension? Or should I reinstall it? Or should I need to reload it again - and how if its possible?

2) should I create  install.rdf, chrome.manifest,  *.xul  files and so in by hand (whick folder structure and so on)? Or is there another simplest way to do this?

3) I don't understand, should i create extensions by  "Add-on SDK" or write by hand with notepad? what is difference of them?

4) I'm writing simplest script, which invoke alert('hello world') when i open any page by browser. what is the best and fastest way to do this?

thanks a lot;

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html#getting-started and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/modifying-web-pages-url.html answers all of your questions.

Comment: someone told me that I can create Firefox Addon project online. do you know where is this?...

Comment: Search for "Add-on builder" or "Jetpack". The online SDK can be found at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/builder. Setting up a local environment is not too difficult, and results in a more efficient workflow, so I recommend to do that instead (see links in my previous comments).

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can I change some code after installing Firefox extension? Or should I reinstall it? Or should I need to reload it again - and how if its possible?

Live updates are possible using `<em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>` and [bootstrap functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions)

> 2) should I create install.rdf, chrome.manifest, *.xul files and so in by hand (whick folder structure and so on)? Or is there another simplest way to do this?

Neither; modify an [existing](https://github.com/dgutov/bmreplace) [simple](https://github.com/cztchoice/vimkey) [extension](https://github.com/benmmurphy/jsdeminifier_xpi)

> 3) I don't understand, should i create extensions by "Add-on SDK" or write by hand with notepad? what is difference of them?

Add-on SDK is an [sdk](/questions/tagged/sdk); by hand is [xul](/questions/tagged/xul); depends on you

> 4) I'm writing simplest script, which invoke alert('hello world') when i open any page by browser. what is the best and fastest way to do this?

hello_world.xpi (chrome / content / hello.xul):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin" type="text/css"?>

<window xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <caption label="Hello World"/>

</window>
```

In addition, [extension development tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) should help.

**References**

- [Explore multithreaded programming in XUL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-multixul/)